# Activator.CreateInstance - Explain it so I can understand

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, singleton

So I am looking at some sample code, and I am not sure what to make of this:

```
    Private Shared _instance As PollsProvider = Nothing

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As PollsProvider
        Get
            If IsNothing(_instance) Then
                _instance = CType(Activator.CreateInstance( _
                    Type.GetType(Globals.Settings.Polls.ProviderType)), PollsProvider)
            End If
            Return _instance
        End Get
    End Property
```

What is the difference between the above and how I would normally make a singleton:

```
    Private Shared _instance As PollsProvider = Nothing

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As PollsProvider
        Get
            If IsNothing(_instance) Then
                _instance = New PollsProvider
            End If
            Return _instance
        End Get
    End Property
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first code fragment reads the type of PollsProvider to create from config, whereas the second has the type of PollsProvider compiled in.  The first fragment therefore allows you to switch in configuration (without a recompile/redeploy) between RealPollsProvider, TestPollsProvider, FiddledByOurEvilPaymastersPollsProvider, etc.

Answer (score 0):

itowlson got it right. I will add it looks like PollsProvider probably a interface or a class that other classes inherit from.